# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '.asp' is not allowed for IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

When i had the website on IIS 6.0, the classic ASP was called correctly from HTML and the email functionality in .asp file used to work. But i changed the IIS to 7.0 from 6.0 and i get this error when .asp is called. I think this has to do with Web.config file for the code to work.

Below is the code in HTML page that calls Classic Asp Page and the website is in asp.net using c#.

```
<form action="sendmail_feedback.asp" method="post" name="feedback" id="feedback" onsubmit="validate()">
```

What do you guys think i should add in web.config for the above piece of code to work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is the asp page even accessible?

Comment: Do you have classic ASP installed and enabled? It isn't installed by default in IIS 7.

Comment: I am sorry @DanielA.White. What exactly is accessible? If you mean, does it open up if not send an email, that's a NO. After the submit button is clicked, it throws the above error :-(

Comment: i mean in a web browser if you go to an asp page, what does it show?

Comment: Yes, i did install classic ASP along with ISAPI , etc ! Thank you @PrestonGuillot !

Comment: "500 - Internal server error." when i open live website in web browser and when i run the code on the server on localhost, it throws the "HTTP verb post.." error!

Comment: can you verify you have IsapiModule for *. in IIS handlers mappings?

Comment: ISAPI-dll and CGI.exe are disabled, @user704988 !! Do i have enable them?

Answer (score 0):

As Preston Guillot wrote, I fixed this by installing classic ASP in the Server manager:

add role/feature
->Web Server(IIS)
->Web Server
->Application Development
->ASP (classic unadorned ASP, not ASP.NET)